# Pantheon-files support for bulk or batch renaming?

Tags: pantheon-files

I would like to rename a number of files in one operation, but it does not appear that pantheon-files supports this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pantheon-files does not currently support bulk renaming, however [this feature is on the wishlist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1439991).

Comment: I'm currently on Pop!_Os and planning to move to elementary OS once Juno is released. I installed the beta release on another machine to test it from time to time. Bulk renaming is one of the features is miss the most.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by integrating into Pantheon Files' context menu an option to use the bulk-rename tool of Thunar file manager, which has many other options than by just one rename-pattern.

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

Then, using `gedit` as text editor:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/rename-bulk.contract
```

with:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Rename file(s) in Thunar
Icon=thunar
MimeType=application/octet-stream
Exec=thunar -B %U
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

[image]